# Objective-C: UITabBarController Black Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

Bellow i have some code that is place in the `app delegate.m` and is used to create a c between two ViewControllers. The creation of the tab bar works fine but when i select the setting tab there is no view it is just black.

Here is the code:

```
import "ViewController.h"
#import "Settings.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

        ViewController *vc1 = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        Settings *vc2 = [[Settings alloc]init];

        [vc1.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Browse"];
        [vc2.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Settings"];

        [tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil]];
        [self.window setRootViewController:tbc];

        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a xib file for Settings? If so, use initWithNibName:bundle: like you did for vc1. Also, it makes no sense to instantiate ViewController, and make it the window's root view controller, only to then instantiate it again, and make it one of the controllers in a tab bar controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write the code for setting screen like this

Settings *vc2 = [[Settings alloc]init];

where is the nib file for setting screen ,

Once try like this

UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

```
ViewController *vc1 = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
Settings *vc2 = [[Settings alloc]initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];

[vc1.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Browse"];
[vc2.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Settings"];

[tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil]];
[self.window setRootViewController:tbc];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: You're code gives an error: `terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:`

Comment: @user2569812, this is the correct way to do this. Do you have a xib file called "Settings.xib"? If not, you need to replace "Settings" in initWithNibName:bundle with the name of your xib file.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    ViewController *vc1 = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    Settings *vc2 = [[Settings alloc]init];

    [vc1.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Browse"];
    [vc2.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Settings"];

    [tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:tbc];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```